# Simple composition of implicits with Monoids in Scala

Tags: scala, monoids

I have the following trait:

```
import scalaz.Monoid

trait Mapper[M, R] {
  def map(m: M): R
}

object Mapper {
  @inline implicit def listMapper[M, R]
            (implicit mapper: Mapper[M, R], s: Monoid[R]): Mapper[List[M], R] =
    (xs: List[M]) => xs. foldLeft(s.zero)((r, m) => s.append(r, mapper.map(m)))
}
```

Now I want to list mapper for with `R = String` that produces something like the following `[mapped_string1, mapped_string2]` or 
`$%%""mapped_string1, mapped_string2""%%$`.

The question is the following monoid implementation will not work:

```
implicit val myStringMonoid: Monoid[String] = new Monoid[String] {
  override def zero = ""
  override def append(f1: String, f2: => String) =
    if (f1.isEmpty) f2
    else if(f2.isEmpty) f1
    else f1 + ", " + f2
}
```

So the following line

```
println(implicitly[Mapper[List[String], String]].map(List("mapped_string1", "mapped_string2")))
```

prints `mapped_string1, mapped_string2` ***without angle brackets***.

What would be a solution for that case? Maybe just monoids does quite fit my needs. Maybe I need another level of abstraction.

I mean how to generally add some additional operation to be invoked after `foldLeft` is finished? Without coupling to `String` or any particular type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
implicit def listMapper[M, R]
    (implicit mapper: Mapper[M, R], s: Monoid[R]): Mapper[List[M], R] = ???
```

means that if you have `Mapper[M, R]` then you have `Mapper[List[M], R]`. But to make this work you should have some initial `Mapper[M, R]`.

So if you want to have `Mapper[List[String], String]` you should add for example

```
implicit def stringMapper: Mapper[String, String] = s => s
```

Then this produces

```
println(implicitly[Mapper[List[String], String]].map(List("mapped_string1", "mapped_string2"))) 
//mapped_string1, mapped_string2

def addBrackets(s: String, openBracket: String, closingBracket: String) = 
    openBracket + s + closingBracket

val s = implicitly[Mapper[List[String], String]].map(List("mapped_string1", "mapped_string2"))
    println(addBrackets(s, "[", "]"))
//[mapped_string1, mapped_string2]
```

Otherwise you can change

```
implicit val myStringMonoid: Monoid[String] = new Monoid[String] {
    override def zero = ""
    override def append(f1: String, f2: => String): String =
      if (f1.isEmpty) f2
      else if(f2.isEmpty) f1
      else f1 + f2 // without  ", "
  }
```

Then

```
val l = "[" ::
  List("mapped_string1", "mapped_string2")
    .flatMap(s => List(", ", s))
    .tail ::: List("]")
println(implicitly[Mapper[List[String], String]].map(l))
//[mapped_string1, mapped_string2]
```

Comment: Yes this is a solution, but is it possible to abstract over types of Monoid (`String` in my case). For instance, I want to get a mapper for `Array[Byte]` and in the case I don't need any surroundings (like `[` and `]` in the case of strings). But such `implicit def listMapper[M, R]` implemetation does not work in that case. Or I missed something?

Comment: I guess you should define `implicit def byteMapper: Mapper[Byte, Byte] = b => b` and `implicit def arrayMapper[M, R](implicit mapper: Mapper[M, R], s: Monoid[R]): Mapper[Array[M], R] = ???`